# Publishing app to google store from android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-console

I have built a app in android studio and would now like to publish it however I am very confused with the process for this. From Android studio I have generated a signed APK file which can be seen in the image below.

[image: Image showing the File of the apk]

I see however that Google play console wants the files in the .AAB file type. How do I generate this/ what is it. The upload console can be seen below.

[image]

This is my first app upload so my questions may make no sense, please let me know in the comments below if there is anything I need to change or additional information required.

Any additional help with publishing apps on google play store will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `.AAB` refers to "Android App Bundle", select `Android App Bundle` instead of `APK` after you clicked `Generated Signed Bundle / APK`, the rest of the procedure is more or less the same. You may refer to the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#sign-apk) for more information

Comment: you should generate signed bundle instead of signed apk from Android studio

Comment: @RickyMo Please submit as a answer. It works perfectly thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.AAB` refers to "Android App Bundle", select `Android App Bundle` instead of `APK` after you clicked `Generated Signed Bundle / APK`, the rest of the procedure is more or less the same. You may refer to the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#sign-apk) for more information